# catkin_make: cmake error: cannot find stdmsgsConfig.cmake

Tags: ros-kinetic, cmake

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am having the following error while trying to using `catkin_make` for my workspace,

```
CMake Error at /opt/ros/kinetic/share/catkin/cmake/catkinConfig.cmake:83 (find_package):
  Could not find a package configuration file provided by "stdmsgs" with any
  of the following names:

    stdmsgsConfig.cmake
    stdmsgs-config.cmake

  Add the installation prefix of "stdmsgs" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set
  "stdmsgs_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above files.  If
  "stdmsgs" provides a separate development package or SDK, be sure it has
  been installed.
```

can anyone please suggest me why ?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/312035/catkin_make:-cmake-error:-cannot-find-stdmsgsconfig.cmake/) by [microbot](https://answers.ros.org/users/39013/microbot/) on ROS Answers with karma: 96 on 2019-01-06

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It looks like you're trying to use the `stdmsgs` package in your `CMakeLists.txt` when it should be `std_msgs`.

---

Originally posted by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) with karma: 6155 on 2019-01-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [microbot](https://answers.ros.org/users/39013/microbot/) on 2019-01-07**:
Thank you, this solved the error and also this helped me understand ros and catkin workspace a bit more. Thank you once again.

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2019-01-07**:
No problem, glad it worked.